# Will sparse row matrix help in computational speed of this code?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have two large `numpy` arrays with integer entries whose entries are mostly 0s.   As an illustration suppose

```py
arr_one = np.array([[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],[3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4]], 
                            [[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],[2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2]]])

arr_two = np.array([[[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7], [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7],[5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 6]], 
                            [[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5], [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4]]])
```

I have another array which is dense with mostly non-zero entries:

```py
arr_main = np.array([[[1, 2, 4],[3, 2, 1],[3, 4, 5]], 
                         [[3, 4, 4],[3, 3, 3],[4, 4, 5]], 
                         [[4, 5, 4],[4, 6, 4],[3, 1, 6]]])
```

These numbers are only for illustrations, and what I am dealing with much larger sized arrays, with mostly 0s as entries for `arr_one` and `arr_two`. Now, I need to set the elements of `arr_main` to 0 based on entries on `arr_one`. The process is quite convoluted and I need to use several `for` loops. Since loops in python are slow, I wrote a `C` code and `weaved` it in my python code. The following describes the `C` code:

```py
code = """
#pragma omp parallel shared(arr_main, arr_one, arr_two, n1, n2) default(none)
{
int row_t, column_p, row, col;
#pragma omp for reduction(+:fl)
for (int i=0; i< n1; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < n2; j++){
        for (row_t = arr_one(0,i,j); row_t < arr_two(0,i,j); row_t++){
            row = row_t % 3;
            for (column_p = arr_one(1,i,j); column_p < arr_two(1,i,j); column_p++){
                col = (column_p - 1) % 3;
                arr_main(row, col, i) = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
"""
arr_main = np.ascontiguousarray(arr_main)
arr_one = np.ascontiguousarray(arr_one)
arr_two = np.ascontiguousarray(arr_two)
n1 = 3
n2 = 6
try:
    if os.uname()[0] == 'Darwin':
        extra_compile_args = extra_link_args = ['-O3']
    else:
        extra_compile_args = extra_link_args = ['-O3 -fopenmp']
    get_flux = scipy.weave.inline(code, ['arr_main', 'arr_one', 'arr_two',  'n1', 'n2'], type_converters=scipy.weave.converters.blitz, compiler='gcc', extra_compile_args=extra_compile_args, extra_link_args=extra_link_args, headers=['<omp.h>','<cmath>'], libraries=['m'], verbose=2)
except:
    get_flux = scipy.weave.inline(code, ['arr_main', 'arr_one', 'arr_two',  'n1', 'n2'], type_converters=scipy.weave.converters.blitz, compiler='gcc', extra_compile_args=['-O3'], extra_link_args=['-O3'], headers=['<cmath>'], libraries=['m'], verbose=2)
```

Since my real arrays are very large, and since `arr_one` and `arr_two` are sparse, is there any way I could utilise `scipy.sparse` to make this computation more efficient and faster?

**Update**

Since I am looping even over elements which are zero, and essentially could be discarded, I create sparse matrix for `arr_one` to get the index of non-zero elements as:

```py
arr_non_zero_first = csc_matrix(arr_one[0]).nonzero()
arr_non_zero_second = csc_matrix(arr_one[1]).nonzero()
```

What I am unsure is how to incorporate this into this `weave` now, just to reduce the number of loops.

Comment: can you split it and make it run across multiple cores?

Comment: @shahaf How do you do that? Also, the since the matrices are really sparce, I really want to know if that could be exploited to improve the efficiency of the code.

Comment: I didn't go over you `c` logic in enough detail so i don't sure if the matrices can be split and calc, but you can utilize the cores with `multiprocessing` lib https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html
to use the sparcity property you need to store the matrix in efficient way like store only the index that aren't zero or such, so you don't need to pass all the matrix values

Comment: Maybe describe your computation more precisely, as it's quite informal, arr_two is not part of it and the C-code is not that much helping with magic-constants.

Comment: @sascha It is mostly setting elements of `arr_main` to zero. Since, the shape of `arr_main` is `(3, 3, 3)`, the `%3` part of the code is to make sure that our indices are in the range of 0 and 3, to avoid out-of-bounds issue. I am not sure what you mean by "`arr_two` is not part of it".

Comment: Are you thinking of using the `mxnet` `csr` or the `scipy.sparse`?  Add the appropriate tag.

Comment: @hpaulj I am thinking of using `scipy.sparse`, but couldn't see the tag. But have added that in my question.